# base64 encodebytes v b64encode v encodestring

Tags: python, base64

What is difference and why/when would I want to use
`base64.b64encode` vs. `base64.encodestring` vs. `base64.encodebytes`?

From what I can tell they all basically do the same thing except that `base64.encodebytes` is no longer [supported](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes)???

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Python 3, `encodestring` is the same as `encodebytes` except that `encodestring` is deprecated. In Python 2, `encodebytes` does not exist.

`b64encode` does a straight encoding, with the option of using alternate characters in the base64 alphabet in place of `+` and `/`.

`encodebytes`/`encodestring` not only encodes but inserts newlines after every 76 characters and at the end of the string. This makes it suitable for inserting directly into an email. It does *not* have an option for alternate characters.

Update: this seems to be an area where there's a lot of churn.  `encodestring` appears to have been removed in Python 3.9 after being deprecated in 3.1.  There's a new `urlsafe_b64encode` which takes a byte string and uses `-` and `_` in place of `+` and `/`, as specified by [RFC 3548](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3548.html#page-6).